# SQL - Summing number of columns which have a true boolean value for a given ID

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, boolean, aggregate

Suppose I have a table of unique transactions with transaction ID, customer ID, and a number of different boolean columns for various features of the transaction. Customers may be associated to more than one transaction.

For each distinct customer, I would like to count how many of the boolean columns have a true value.

Columns in table: transact_id, customer_id, bool_one, bool_two, bool_three...

| transact_id | customer_id | bool_one | bool_two | bool_three |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | x | True | False | False |
| 10002 | x | True | True | False |
| 10003 | y | False | False | True |

Output

| Customer | Number of columns |
| --- | --- |
| x | 2 |
| y | 1 |

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Comment: `case when boolcol is true then 1 else 0 end + case when ...`

Comment: Thank you, I've edited my question to provide more information.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using?

Comment: Google Big Query

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
select customer_id, 
  cast(logical_or(bool_one) as int64) 
  + cast(logical_or(bool_two) as int64) 
  + cast(logical_or(bool_three) as int64) as col_num
from your_table
group by customer_id
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]